# Find and extract the next word after the search term using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking through text strings of variable length to see what chemicals were applied. The chemical name is usually given after the word "apply" or "spray". Therefore I want to extract the next word after the term "spray" or "apply" has been used. The search strings are of variable length and the search terms are not in the same place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some sample data, the expected result, and what you have tried so far, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Mid` and `search` functions, you can find the next word. This assumes that the words are all separated by single spaces, which may not be true.

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,SEARCH("apply",A2)+6,SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH("apply",A2)+6)-6-SEARCH("apply",A2)),MID(A2,SEARCH("spray",A2)+6,SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH("spray",A2)+6)-6-SEARCH("spray",A2)))
```

Comment: Dear Greg. Many thanks for the answer this appears to work very well. Thanks for saving my sanity! Is there any way to cope with terms that are not separated by regular single spaces? Many thanks

Comment: The formula gets very long very quickly the more situations it addresses. I would suggest a VBA custom function at that point.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the text is in cell A1, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Spray",A1,1))=TRUE,LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("apply",A1)-5),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("apply",A1)-5))-1),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("spray",A1)-5),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("spray",A1)-5))-1))
```

The formula will look for the word "spray" first and if it's not found will look for "apply". The formula returns the word after "spray"/"apply".

Comment: Dear Kaiser, Thank you for your very swift reply. The formula appears to work when spray is the first term, but not when apply is the search term

Comment: @reeder: I've updated the formula, now should work well for both words